# Changing img src with the fileupload value using jquery/php/html

Tags: php, jquery, image, file-upload, preview

I'm working on a facebook tab that accepts some text and also a picture using an html fileUpload component, the idea is that when the user selects a picture in the fileUpload component, the image they select appears on the page as a way of previewing the picture before uploading it to the server. I tried fectching the image url using val(), but for security reasons, browsers do not give the complete url of a local file. Is there a way to do this using either php or jquery?

Thanks

Comment: you can use [HTML5 filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: Never used it before, but it seems that the HTML5 FileReader API is not supported in IE9 [according to this](http://caniuse.com/filereader), and it needs to work in that browser too :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this is what you're looking for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images):

```
function handleFiles(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
      continue;
    }

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    preview.appendChild(img);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

You might also be interested in reading other examples, like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images).

**Edit:** This method relies on the `FileReader` API, so it won't work on IE9 as you've pointed out, but I don't think it is possible otherwise.
At the end of the day, do you *need* IE9 compatibility ?  You might find it acceptable to add a functionality that works for all but a few percent of your user base.

Comment: Thanks! this will have to do due to the timing of the project, works like a charm in every browser except IE9